# how to visualize rgbdslam's map on RVIZ?

Tags: ros, rgbdslam-freiburg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello I'm a student.
I want to visualize rgbdslam's map on RVIZ.
Where do I need changing that program?
rgbdslam published topics batch_clouds,aggregate_clouds and online_cloud(sensor_msgs/pointcloud2)
I have to create new publisher? type of (nav_msgs/OccupancyGrid)?
Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/249075/how-to-visualize-rgbdslam%27s-map-on-rviz?/) by [kionawalker](https://answers.ros.org/users/28664/kionawalker/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-11-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you tried displaying batch_clouds in rviz?

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2016-12-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1